# Changing url for the pages with onbeforeunload

Tags: testing, selenium, phpunit, selenium-webdriver

This question is mostly particularly about `phpunit_selenium2` extension (though the general ideas are welcome as well):

Let's say I have a page that fires an alert on the browser/tab closing event with something like this:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return 'Hello world!';
};
```

The test opens this page, performs some actions and according to the test scenario I need to open another url.

The issue is that the command

```
$this->url('/another/page/url');
```

waits for the page url to be changed and fails because it doesn't - since it's locked by the just appeared alert window: `RuntimeException: Navigation failed with error code=3.`

How would one solve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ugly but the only solution I could think of:

```
try {
    $this->url('/another/page/url');
} catch (RuntimeException $e) {}
$this->acceptAlert();
```